Early hint: preload cookie consent manager but script not executing with warning: not used within a few seconds from the window's load event
I'm currently trying to use early hints to preload a script that is used to implement the Cookie Consent Manager (CCM19) to my website which im developing with TYPO3 CMS. I used 3 different ways to do it but i always get a warning message in the console:

The resource  was preloaded using link preload but not used
within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it
has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.

I used the following methods to preload the script.
NGINX
add_header Link "<www.example.com/app.js?apiKey=000000&amp;domain=111111>; rel=preload; as=script";

TypoScript
config.additionalHeaders {
    100.header = Link: <www.example.com/app.js?apiKey=000000&amp;domain=111111>; rel=preload; as=script
}

HTML DOM
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="www.example.com/app.js?apiKey=000000&amp;domain=111111" referrerpolicy="origin">

I don't know what i can do to solve this problem but usually the script executes itself and adds a new stylsheet and another script.
Do i miss anything or did anything wrong?

Maybe your resources do not have the same paths? (In your snippets, you are using sometimes the protocol, sometime not). See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70456280/6783328

The different protocol is only in my snippets, i did forgot to change it after replacing the original url. When using one of the methods mentioned, i always only used one at the time and I haven't requested the link anywhere else, since i was told that i dont need to include it in the html dom as I usually do with <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="www.example.com/app.js?apiKey=000000&amp;domain=111111"></script>
